# Is there a jQuery Equivalent of YUI 2 Custom Event Publish/Subscribe Event Model?

Tags: jquery, publish-subscribe, custom-event

I learned how to develop in Javascript using the YUI 2 library and was wondering if there were a jQuery equivalent of Custom Events (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#customevent)

Specifically, I want to be able to define custom events without having to attach the listeners initially.

In YUI, I would create a page class and declare different custom events that can be subscribed to. Below is some example code to demonstrate what I want to do, but with jQuery

```
function ListPage() {
    var me = this;
    this.initEvent = new YAHOO.util.CustomEvent("initEvent");

    this.init = function() {
         // initialize events, DOM, etc
         this.initEvent.fire(me);
    }
}
```

In application Javascript, I would then like to subscribe to the initEvent.

```
var page = new ListPage();
page.initEvent.subscribe(
    function (type, args) {
        // do stuff here
    }
);

page.init();
```

Are there any tutorials/examples of something like this in jQuery?

I understand I can do something similar using bind() and trigger(), but the impression I get is I have to pass in an event handler when I call bind().

Is it possible in jQuery to create the custom event, but pass in the event handler later?

I hope my question makes sense. thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of pub/sub plugins for jquery.

Example - Rebecca Murphy [screencast](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/loose-coupling-with-the-pubsub-plugin/)

Plugins - [Ben Almans pubsub](https://gist.github.com/743922), [Phiggins pubsub](https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js)

Comment: The screencast by Rebecca Murphy covers exactly what I was looking for. thank you!

Comment: Just wanted to added that the Phiggins pubsub plugin is absolute amazing!

Comment: It seems the link to Rebecca Murphy's screencast is dead.  I tried to find it but didn't have any luck.  I think the video is published here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/loose-coupling-with-the-pubsub-plugin/ , though, I think the reccomended implementation is this one currently: https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js